# Make markers iteractive to show infowindow on click

Tags: carto, carto-js

I've used in my html file:

```
var layerSource = {
            user_name: 'username',
            type: 'cartodb',
            sublayers: [{
                sql: "SELECT * FROM post",
                cartocss: '#post {marker-fill: red;}',interactivity: "cod",
           }] 
}
```

And it displays all my markers.
Now I need to display windows about each marker within their field when on an onclick event. But the markers aren't interactive and so I can't display the windows.

Answer (score 1):

Click events are trickier when using `createLayer` from a custom layer definition instead of using a viz.json and setting it up in CartoDB's editor, but it's totally possible and you have some great options for customizing the infowindows.

One option is to setup an infowindow with the following code (note that it has to be in the same scope as the `layer` and `map` objects:

```
cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(map, layer.getSubLayer(1), ['name', 'description', 'place', 'date', 'url'], {
                 infowindowTemplate: $('#infowindow_template').text(),
                 templateType: 'mustache',
                 triggerEvent: 'featureClick',
                 cursorInteraction: true
             });
```

Where the template was defined earlier as:

```
<script id='infowindow_template' type="infowindow/html">
    <div class="cartodb-popup v2">
      <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
      <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
        <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
          <h4>name</h4>
          <p>{{content.data.name}}</p>
          <h4>place</h4>
          <p>{{content.data.place}}</p>
          <h4>date</h4>
          <p>{{content.data.date}}</p>
          {{#content.data.url}}
          <h4>Workshop Information</h4>
          <p><a href="{{url}}">{{content.data.description}}</a></p>
          {{/content.data.url}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

A second option is to create your own infowindows from the callback objects of click or hover events. I made an example of that here: http://bl.ocks.org/andy-esch/a0e06de1f6f1597c096b

The key piece of code is:

```
sublayer.on('featureOver', function(e, latlng, pos, data, layerNumber) {
    cartodb.log.log(e, latlng, pos, data, layerNumber);
    $("#hover").css({'display':'block','left':pos.x-75,'bottom':($(window).height()-pos.y+20), 'cursor': 'pointer'});
    $("#hover").find('p').text(data.place);
});
sublayer.on('featureOut', function(e,latlng, pos, data, layerNumber) {
    $("#hover").css({'display':'none'});
});
```

With the `hover` HTML being just a div element that is filled with the content you choose.